# Failed to load AppCompat ActionBar with unknown error. Tip: Try to refresh the layout

Tags: android-studio

I looked for already asked question but they was on older version of android studio and they doesn't work. As you can see I don;t have buildToolsVersion,compile  and classpath 
.My gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.illuminat.button"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

Answer (score 4):

1. Open app Build.gradle file.
2. In dependencies replace: 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha3'by
   'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0-alpha1'
3. Clic en Sync.

Comment: Even though the fix involves changing to an older and possibly more buggy dep, it does get the job done.

Answer (score 0):

In res/values/style.xml change style tag to

Comment: To what should I change that resource file tag??